# Split dictionary based on values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
```

I'm trying to split the dictionary `data` into number of dictionaries based on values in key `mount`.

I tried using:

```
for value in data.items():
    print(data)
```

But I get this:

```
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
```

Actually, I would like to get:

```
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': 'C'}
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': 'D'}
data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': 'E'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [dict(zip(data.keys(), prod)) for prod in product(*data.values())]
[{'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'C', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'D', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'E', 'node': 'B'}]
```

It would even work if another variable contains a list:

```
>>> data = {'cluster': ['A', 'B'], 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
>>> [dict(zip(data.keys(), prod)) for prod in product(*data.values())]
[{'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'C', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'B', 'mount': 'C', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'D', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'B', 'mount': 'D', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'E', 'node': 'B'},
 {'cluster': 'B', 'mount': 'E', 'node': 'B'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the value-list at key `'mount'`, and update the value at that key:

```
>>> data = {'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': ['C', 'D', 'E']}
>>> 
>>> for v in data['mount']:
...    d = data.copy()
...    d['mount'] = v
...    print(d)
... 
{'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'C'}
{'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'D'}
{'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'E'}
```

You could also build all the dicts in a list using a *list comprehension* given the value-list location is already known:

```
>>> [{'cluster': 'A', 'node': 'B', 'mount': v} for v in data['mount']]
[{'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'C'}, 
 {'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'D'}, 
 {'node': 'B', 'cluster': 'A', 'mount': 'E'}]
```