# Split dictionary into multiple dicts based on List value

Tags: python

I'm working with a nested mongo backend and am in the process of mapping it to SQL database tables. A user can fill in forms which will be stored as following

```
{
  "response": {
    "question_1": "answer_1",
    "question_2": [
      "answer_a",
      "answer_b"
    ]
  },
  "user": "user_1",
  "form_id": "2344"
}
```

Questions can have multiple answers stored as an array.
I would like to flatten this into a long format (Ie a single record per question-answer combination) like so

```
[
{
  "question_id": "question_1",
  "answer": "answer_1",
  "user": "user_1",
  "form_id": "2344"
},
{
  "question_id": "question_2",
  "answer": "answer_a",
  "user": "user_1",
  "form_id": "2344"
},
{
  "question_id": "question_2",
  "answer": "answer_b",
  "user": "user_1",
  "form_id": "2344"
}
]
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this in python?
I could brute-force it by looping over every response in the response dict but I have the feeling that's overkill...

Many thanks

EDIT:
A first working attempt uses the following function:

```
def transform_responses_to_long(completed_form: Dict):
    responses = completed_form["response"]
    del completed_form["response"]
    for key, values in responses.items():
        if not isinstance(values, (List, Dict)):
            values = [values]
        for value in values:
            result = {}
            result.update(completed_form)
            result.update({"question_id": key, "answer": value})
            yield result
```

Which yields the correct dict for every question: answer combination

Comment: have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044751/split-dictionary-based-on-values

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the above link, iterators seem the way to go. However, the product function does not look like a good fit for mapping the response keys to question_id's. I edited my post with a working example but I am sure this can be done better